# Firefox selenium webdriver hanging upon initializing - is my setup correct?

Tags: python, selenium

I am testing a website and I am using [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) to automate it. My applications hangs right after it launches the browser. There might be an issue with my config - here's my setup:

```
python==3.6
selenium==2.53.6
firefox==58

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=LEVEL)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    if ATTACK_REDDIT:
        driver.get("http://mywebsite.com")
        ....
```

Any ideas? Here's the output from the console:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 173.4127.16)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1668, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1662, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1072, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/simon/PycharmProjects/uncaptcha/main.py", line 363, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/simon/PycharmProjects/uncaptcha/main.py", line 293, in main
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/Users/simon/PycharmProjects/uncaptcha/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "/Users/simon/PycharmProjects/uncaptcha/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Users/simon/PycharmProjects/uncaptcha/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
  File "/Users/simon/PycharmProjects/uncaptcha/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 108, in _wait_until_connectable
    % (self.profile.path))
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /var/folders/8r/rttp99k95xx4d6b2h_596jfr0000gn/T/tmpup78c87x If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Comment: what is the error code you are getting?? please paste the console log for better support

Comment: Try downgrading your firefox below 48.0 version

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use Firefox 47 or older with selenium 2.53. I had this issue using selenium with Java. Either try to downgrade Firefox or upgrade selenium and switch to the gecko driver.